# Completely remove configuration from root in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, configuration, hierarchy

In ASP.Net, if we create application from directory, the configuration from root will be inherited to its children application.

```
www.mywebsite.com
 |
 |-- [blog]
 |-- [forum]
 |-- [others]
```

so I created these `blog`, `forum` application but I don't want configuration from `www.mywebsite.com`/web.config inherited to `blog` & `forum`.

I know i can remove it one by one using `<remove>` in `www.example.com/blog/web.config`. But, is there any simpler way to children application just IGNORE everything on its parent configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the '[inheritInChildApplications="false"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.inheritinchildapplications.aspx)'

Also, instead of the `<remove name='lalala'>` you can use the `<clear />` to remove all the items in a section. Not perfect but easier.

Comment: where to put option inheritInChildApplications="false" ? I put it in root, but child application still read root config

Comment: here's an example: http://www.jaylee.org/post/2008/03/Prevent-ASPNET-webconfig-inheritance-and-inheritInChildApplications-attribute.aspx